# Rewrite Results in NGINX

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, nginx

The `RewriteRule` written in a CentOS environment doesn't work with NGINX environment even after conversion.

Can anyone guide me, what syntax needs to be followed in an NGINX environment for Drupal rewriting rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For URL rewrites in Drupal, please put the following in your nginx vhost configuration within the `location /` section of the `server` section:

```
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
            break;
        }
```

As described here: https://www.drupal.org/node/110224